# TFS REST API - search

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to use the TFS REST API for searching our repo.  It seems the request I have is working but I only get a count of results back and no actual result data. Probably something simple but not obvious to me.

---

(POST)

http://{tfsserver}:8080/tfs/{repo}/{project}/_apis/search/codesearchresults?api-version=5.0-preview.1

(Body)

```
{
  "searchText": "what",
  "$skip": 0,
  "$top": 10,
  "filters": null,
  "sortOptions":"",
  "$orderBy": null,
  "includeFacets": false
}
```

Result: 200 OK

```
{
    "count": 533,
    "results": [],
    "infoCode": 0,
    "facets": {}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What **version** of TFS?

Comment: @jd314159 Is that working using other `searchText` as suggested by Cece ? If that still doesn't work, please provide the version of TFS you are using, so we can investigate it further.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested in AzureDevOps2019.Update1.1, this API is working as expected:

[image]

Please check your DevOps server version and use other "searchText" to see whether you can get the result.